# Executing SQL query in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array

I have this query in Ruby to fetch some data from the database:

```
@mastertest = connection.execute("select code_ver, date from mastertest")
```

So now I assume `@mastertest` is a 2-dimensional array containing all rows and columns

I try this to print everything out:

```
@mastertest.each do |row|
  puts row[0]
end
```

And it prints the first column of all rows.

Now I want to find out the unique values from the first column of all rows and count the number of it's occurrence too. I know it can be done through Hash or Array. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = @mastertest.map{ |row| row[0] }.uniq
result.size #=> number of occurrences
```

Comment: I want to assign the result to another 2d array to print the results....so should i do something like this: 

@temp = @mastertest.map{ |row| row[0] }.uniq.size

???

Comment: Is result an array here? Because I am not getting the result I intend to get.

To be more clear, the first row in my 2D-array will have data like this : 111,222,222,333,111

So my output should be a 2d array such that 
result=[ {111,2}, {222,2}, {333,1} ]

Comment: Try to print to understand what kind of data you have "{ |row| puts row; row[0]}"

Comment: I am quite new to ruby on rails...and when I make any changes in my controller, I cannot see the output being printed when i start my server.....I am testing my results by just making changes in my view....can you help me out here?